# Store user credential

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I tried to store  user credential in registry editor.It was successfully worked.

```
  RegistryKey key;
  key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\XXX\\Credential");
  key.SetValue("Name", txtusername);
  key.SetValue("Password", password);
  key.Close();
```

how to store user credential securely in credential manager for wpf application?

Comment: What credential manager?

Comment: Credential manager was used to store user credential.It was stored user password securely.It was located in control panel(Control Panel\User Accounts and Family Safety\Credential Manager). The below link how to store user credential in credential manager in "windows store application".                   http://eren.ws/2013/10/21/storing-user-credentials-securely-in-windows-store-apps-boredom-challenge-day-17/.                        My Question is: how to store user credential in credential manager in wpf application?

Answer (score 0):

If the credentials are to be used only from within the application itself then you can  encrypt them and add them to your app.config file.

Create an application setting of type connectionstring and call it say myconnectionstring

Using Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder you can build then "connection string" with your username and password off the back of a dialog box that asks the user to enter them.

Then (in VB)

```
        Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
        Dim section As System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection = DirectCast(config.GetSection("connectionStrings"), System.Configuration.ConnectionStringsSection)

        section.ConnectionStrings(My.Settings.ToString & ".myconnectionstring").ConnectionString = ConnectionString

        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")

        config.Save(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)

        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings")
```

This should save it encrypted in app.config

When read the data back out, .Net will take care of all of the decryption for you.

Simply create another Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder object, assign its connectionstring property to `Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(My.Settings.ToString & ".myconnectionstring").connectionstring` then read fields you need.

Hope this helps